# How to update MySQL column/row when datetime column < now?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am making a platform where people can make bids on items for a price.

I want to make it so that after a the expire datetime of the item, the database will automatically update the status of the item from "Open" to "Expired" and then send an email to the item owner and bidders to let them know of the new status.

How do I achieve this?

I am using PHP as my scripting language and AWS to send emails.

Is this done in PHP or in MySQL?

Comment: This will be a two-part task. First, make sure that users cannot bid on something if it is still "Open" but has logically expired. Second, look into cron. Basically, you want the system to run a task periodically (every minute, five minutes, etc.) and that task is find all "Open but expired" items, mark them as "Expired" and perform additional logic. For additional logic, you might also want to look into queues.

Comment: awesome, please elaborate on cron and queues if possible, i am new to this

Comment: `cron` is a standard concept for Linux/Unix (and Windows has a similar). AWS has a [cron thing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html), too. I would just research "how does cron work" to learn about it in details. But generally speaking, you ask the system (host OS) to run a specific file of your choosing at specific times/intervals. The file you want is normal PHP except that you should assume the globals like `$_GET` and such don't exist. You can manually test this by running `php you-file.php`. A queue is a much larger subject.

Comment: I wouldn't bother updating the database. I'd ignore the comments above, if I were you.

Comment: what would you suggest then?

Answer (score 1):

Do not go through the table changing the status.  Compute the status as you do the `SELECT`.

It will be significantly faster, and possibly simpler when you look at all the moving parts.

> It queries all users who posted a bid on the item, then sends an email to each, letting them know it expired and check the results

That must be done by code outside MySQL.  Such a program would poll the database periodically (every minute?) with the statement below.  When it finds some matches, it sends the emails and sets the status to "email_sent" (or whatever).

```
SELECT ...
    FROM tbl
    WHERE this_date < NOW()   -- (I don't know the exact test you need)
      AND status != 'email_sent'
```

and have

```
INDEX(this_date)
```

Updating the status is needed, else you could miss some rows over time, or maybe duplicate some emails.  Since sending an email is a bit costly, you could update them one row at a time.

Comment: so you are saying, only update the actual status when someone queries the row after the status is expired. sure thats easy. but how do you send notifications/emails when the date has passed?, but also not update the row?

Comment: @BrettMalone - The "open" and "expired" status are computed by comparing `NOW()` to some date(s) in the table.  The "email_sent" status would be stored in the table when you send an email; it may factor into the overall status, too.  What are the status values?

Comment: basically, its an item, that accepts bids until `expire date <= now()`. Once that statement becomes true, It queries all users who posted a bid on the item, then sends an email to each, letting them know it expired and check the results. My question is how do I do this? Just ignore the status value for now, im trying to provide a simple example, but there are multiple status's